# Duplicates Based on Three Columns

Tags: python, pandas

So I have a dataset with columns

```
Date, Name, Type, ....
```

I am trying to find a way to grab the duplicates of ALL three merged as an index, but it doesn't seem to be working.  I tried setting the index and then trying to get duplicates, but it doesn't seem to give me them back correctly.

I did:

```
pc = pc.set_index(['name', 'date', 'type']).sort_index()
pc[pc.index.duplicated()]
```

But this is seemingly returning WAY more than I expected.

Answer (score 1):

Use parameter `keep=False` for this:

```
pc = pd.DataFrame([[0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
                   [0, 1, 2, 4, 5],
                   [0, 2, 3, 5, 6]],
                  columns=['name', 'date', 'type', 'val', 'val2'])

pc = pc.set_index(['name', 'date', 'type']).sort_index()

res = pc[pc.index.duplicated(keep=False)]

#                 val  val2
# name date type           
# 0    1    2       3     4
#           2       4     5
```

As per the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.duplicated.html):

> **keep** : *{‘first’, ‘last’, False}, default ‘first’*
>
> • first : Mark duplicates as True except for the first occurrence.
>   • last : Mark duplicates as True except for the last occurrence.
>   • False : Mark all duplicates as True.

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html) we can see that the `subset` argument should achieve what you want:

```
# Get the boolean mask
pc.duplicated(['name', 'date', 'type'])

# Only keep duplicates
df[df.duplicated(subset=['name', 'date', 'type'])]

# Only keep unique (using the `first` strategy)
df[~df.duplicated(subset=['name', 'date', 'type'])]
```